# Making Training Platform Need Python Recommendation

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, video-player

I am relatively new to Python and need some recommendations on what libraries to learn and use for my goal. I have experience programming in obj-c, and am blown away at how much easier Python is.

### Objective:

Make a Training Application using python on Windows.

### Must-Haves:

- GUI with buttons
- Play inline training games (2D)
- Play inline video with media controls
- Load content via a Training Pack (Folder: videos, question/answer list, audio files, images, etc)

I've searched and found many different libraries each with great capabilities, but lacking in others.

**What do you gurus recommend?**

Comment: Gurus recommend hiring a [freelancer](https://www.google.com/search?q=hire+a+freelancer).

Comment: Very funny. True in an ideal world yes. But no funding can be allocated. This is a side project I'll be working on when things are slow.